# Can you help me with this foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

```
$cat_id=$_GET['cat_id'];
$catEx = explode(' ',$cat_id);
foreach($catEx as $exCat)
{
    $looped .= 'ad_cat LIKE'.' '.'%'."$exCat".'%'.' OR '.'ad_title LIKE'.' '.'%'."$exCat".'%'.' OR '.'ad_sub_cat LIKE'.' '.'%'."$exCat".'%'.' OR '.'ad_description LIKE'.' '.'%'."$exCat".'%' ;
}
```

I need to make it so the search bar searches multiple words.

Comment: What's the sample input? What's the current result using that input? What's the desired result using that input?

Comment: Wow, that's a confusing string. I have a feeling that your variables aren't properly quoted. Using prepared statements will help with that.

Comment: @Philipp yeah I forgot to remove it when I double check his code :P

Comment: Removing all of the concatenation, your string becomes `$looped .= 'ad_cat LIKE %$exCat% OR ad_title LIKE %$exCat% OR ad_sub_cat LIKE %$exCat% OR ad_description LIKE %$exCat%' ;`. As you can see here, your variables are not quoted. You can leave the string as I pasted and add just the double quotes around the variables/placeholders, or use prepared statements so you'll never have to worry about quoting issues ever again.

Comment: @aynber not or - he should definitly use prepared statements

Comment: @Philipp Very true. Always use prepared, except when one can't. And if it's not possible, upgrade. No mention of which API is being used, but for the OP, the links are here for [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). A bit of other preparation would need to be made for the foreach loop.

Comment: @aynber but fighting quoting issues is so fun!!! ;)

Comment: @IncredibleHat You and I have a very different definition of fun. ;-) LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add parenthesis around each group of your like conditions so each of the values gets checked for in each column.

```
$cat_id=$_GET['cat_id'];
$catEx = explode(' ',$cat_id);
foreach($catEx as $exCat) {
    $looped .= "(ad_cat         LIKE '%$exCat%' OR 
                 ad_title       LIKE '%$exCat%' OR 
                 ad_sub_cat     LIKE '%$exCat%' OR 
                 ad_description LIKE '%$exCat%') OR ";
}
$looped = trim($looped,' OR '); //just added some spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

as stated by @aynber on comments use sprintf

```
 sprintf ( 'column like "%%s%" or column like "%%s%"', 'string', 'string');
```

Comment: Whoa, I never said anything about sprintf. I said prepared statements. Not the same thing.

Comment: Also its kind of rude to just answer with someone else's comment... especially when its not even what they said ;)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try This Code

```
$cat_id=$_GET['cat_id'];//cute cat
$catEx = explode(' ',$cat_id);
$looped = [];
foreach($catEx as $exCat) {
    $looped[] = "ad_cat         LIKE '%$exCat%' OR 
                 ad_title       LIKE '%$exCat%' OR 
                 ad_sub_cat     LIKE '%$exCat%' OR 
                 ad_description LIKE '%$exCat%'";
}
echo implode(" OR ",$looped);
```